# R || package: usage for function with many parameter

Tags: r, r-markdown, documentation, devtools

In an R package I've a function that takes many parameters. They have default values as NULL or TRUE/FALSE based on their nature. Everything looks good except when I define `@usage` R CMD CHECK says that all parameters are to be present. It errors out in different ways:

```
 Mismatches in argument names:
Codoc mismatches from documentation object
```

I'd like to avoid it for various reasons: 1) it is too long, 2) It may confuse users as I provide examples in `@examples`

```
#' @title many_params
#' @description The function returns a matrix
#' @usage many_params(data_genetic,data_snp_annotation,keep_samples=NULL,remove_genes=NULL,exclude_SNP=NULL,impute_missing=FALSE,default_method="median")
#'
many_params<-function(data_genetic,data_snp_annotation,keep_samples=NULL,remove_genes=NULL,exclude_SNP=NULL,impute_missing=FALSE,default_method="median"){

@export

#' @param data_genetic a dataframe for genetic 
#' @param data_genetic a dataframe for data_snp_annotation where columns are present
#' @param keep_samples details
#' @param remove_genes details
#' @param exclude_SNP details
#' @param impute_missing details
#' @param default_method is mean (activated only when impute_missing =TRUE)
##do many things
#' @examples
#'
return(data_genetic)

}
#
```

I tried with `@usage many_params(data_genetic,data_snp_annotation, ...)` but it generated errors with R CMD check. R-4.0.

How can I keep usage small without specifying all the parameters and pass R CMD CHECK?
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but no can do. The documentation of every R function must show a call with all parameters and their defaults in *Usage*. Not showing that will confuse (experienced) users.

Comment: It it's too confusing to users, you might instead consider simplify your function parameter list to take a list of less commonly used parameters, though that does make them less discoverable.

Comment: @Roland  and MrFlick thank you.